# .bat file doesn't work with comments at top?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a .bat file I made to combine multiple files into a new file and it previously looked like this:

```
copy /b ^
E:\file1.txt+^
E:\file2.txt+^
E:\file3.txt ^
E:\output.txt
:: comment
```

That worked great. I then wanted to add a comment above the code, so I changed it to this:

```
:: comment
:: comment

copy /b ^
E:\file1.txt+^
E:\file2.txt+^
E:\file3.txt ^
E:\output.txt
:: comment
```

It no longer works. Nothing is printed out to the terminal when I run it.

If I remove the comments at the top, it immediately starts working again.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

I guess I shouldn't have simplified my code so much. One of the comments at the top of the file is actually like this:

```
:: E:\file3.txt+^
```

Playing around with it, I've found having the characters `+^` in the comment causes the file to not work.

I also tried using `REM` on this line, but it results in an error being printed out. So it seems that there are characters you simply cannot have in comments?

Comment: As written in your question, there is nothing wrong with the code in your question. There must be additional or different code than what you are showing. For example, an IF or FOR statement with parentheses around the code would cause problems.

Comment: @dbenham I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` character at the end of a line acts as line continuation. (It works by escaping the line feed).

Line continuation does not work after `REM` (with a few exceptions) - all characters after the `REM` are generally ignored.

Line continuation does work after `::`, so your entire script becomes one big comment.

You can fix it by removing the trailing `^` from the comment, or by adding another character after the `^`, or by using `REM` instead of `::`.

There are some cases where a REM comment can be continued to the next line:

```
@echo off
:: This is a multi-line comment ^
This line is a continuation of the comment above

:: This comment ^ does not continue
echo This line 1 is executed

rem This comment does not continue ^
echo This line 2 is executed

rem.This is a multi-line comment ^
This is a continuation of the comment above

rem^ This is a multi-line comment ^
This is a continuation of the comment above

rem^,This is a multi-line comment ^
This is a continuation of the comment above

rem^;This is a multi-line comment ^
This is a continuation of the comment above

rem^=This is a multi-line comment ^
This is a continuation of the comment above

rem^:This is a multi-line comment ^
This is a continuation of the comment above
```

I'm not aware of any comment style that is universally safe regardless of content. For example, a comment containing invalid expansion syntax will result in a fatal syntax error!

```
rem %~x This comment containing invalid expansion results in a fatal error
echo This line is never reached
```

The `::` style comment suffers the same fate

```
:: %~x This comment containing invalid expansion results in a fatal error
echo This line is never reached
```

Answer (score 5):

`::` are not comments, but labels.

To make a comment, start the line off with `Rem` instead of `::`

"Rem" is short for remark.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `::` as a comment, unless it appears within a parenthesized block. There must be more to the story than is shown in the question.

Comment: @dbenham actually, If I remember correctly there *are* known issues in using `::` as a comment

Comment: No, it is extremely reliable, unless it appears within a parenthesized block. It can even be used within parentheses if certain rules are followed, but it is not recommended. If you look at my StackOverflow profile you will see that I work with batch files all the time, and virtually all my comments are `::` unless within parentheses.

Comment: @Keltari I updated my question.

Comment: I forgot about line continuation as another issue. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/794231/109090)